# Finding the asymptotic distribution

Tags: self-study, asymptotics

Let

$$Y_n=e^{\frac{-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}$$

with $X_1,...,X_n$ being $n$ i.i.d. Poisson random variables.

In order to find the distribution of $Y_n$ as $n\to\infty$, I first calculate

$$P(Y_n\le y)=P(e^{\frac{-1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}\le y)=P(\ln{y^{-n}}\le \sum_{i=1}^nX_i)$$

Since $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is Poisson distributed, the cdf of $Y_n$ can be found as

$$P(Y_n\le y)=1-e^{-n\lambda}\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\ln{y^{-n}}\rfloor}\frac{(n\lambda)^i}{i!}$$

but how should I proceed from here?

Edit:

$$\sqrt{n}(\ln{Y_n^{-1}}-\lambda)\to N(0,\lambda)$$

Comment: Why not first consider the asymptotic distribution of $\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)/n$?  Surely you already know at least one theorem that will let you deduce that easily.

Comment: Sure, but can I directly apply the CLT to an exponent?

Comment: You should tag with self-study!

Comment: Although the CLT does not apply directly, intuitively if the exponent approaches normality, then $Y_n$ should approach lognormality.  All that remains is to justify this conclusion.

Comment: So some kind of proof is required right? Can it be done using elementary calculus? Cause that's the only tool I have.

Comment: Take natural logs and transform the expression so as the right-hand side becomes something that obeys the CLT. In this way you will find a function of $Y_n$ (the left hand side), that obeys the CLT.

Comment: Please refer to the edit above; should the final distribution of $Y$ contain any $n$? Since I can't get rid of the $\sqrt{n}$ on the left-hand side... .

Comment: Or does $Y_n$ actually converge to a constant, not a distribution...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the OP responded in the suggestions in the comments, let's see the elementary approach here:

$$Y_n=e^{-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i} \implies \ln Y_n = -\bar X_n  $$

The Possion distribution (with parameter $\lambda$) does not have zero mean, so we must center in order to obtain the CLT

$$\ln Y_n + \lambda = -\bar X_n + \lambda = -(\bar X-\lambda)$$

We know that $\sqrt {n}(\bar X-\lambda) \to_d N(0,\lambda)$ *and the same holds for its negative* (due to the symmetry of the normal distribution).So

$$\sqrt {n}(\ln Y_n + \lambda) \to_d Z \sim N(0,\lambda)$$

which is *a* "asymptotic distribution" of $Y_n$, in the sense that we have found a *function* of $Y_n$ that converges to the zero-mean normal distribution.  Then approximately, we have that for large (but finite) samples, moving things around,

$$Y_n \sim_{approx.} e^W,\;\;\; W = \frac 1{\sqrt{n}}Z -\lambda \implies W \sim N(-\lambda, \lambda/n)$$

which tells us that for large but finite $n$, $Y_n$ follows  a log-normal distribution with the above underlying parameters.

At the limit, $Y_n$ uncentered and unscaled converges to a constant of course.

Comment: @yi416 It appears my answer was useful to you. If so, please upvote it and/or tick the check mark to accept it, so that your question leaves the queue of unanswered questions. Thank you.